# Type error while using react-bootstarp Form.Label with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap with typescript.

This is the error I am getting

```
Property 'Label' does not exist on type 'typeof Form'
```

This is the code. Please anyone suggest how can I fix it.

```
<div className = {half ? "halfWidth" : "fullWidth"} >
        <Form.Label>{lableText}</Form.Label>
        <FormControl
        className='p-2 mb-2'
        aria-label="Recipient's username"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
        />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Sandip, Have you installed the types ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the types:

```
npm install --save @types/react-bootstrap
```